# '1 out of 3 million' v. '1 million out of 3 million'

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Can I omit the first word in the expressions like '1 million out of 3 million'? It seems redundant, but I'm not sure whether it would be correct.

Comment: It would NOT be correct. In some circumstances it might cause both a lot of confusion and a great deal of money. Imagine someone saying that **one out of three million people were affected** and wondering what they meant.

Comment: "One out of 3 million" has a well-defined meaning that is one million times smaller than "one million out of 3 million". However, if you are only interested in the ratio, and in saving words, it means the same as "one out of three". Even if you are speaking about a sample of three million, you can say "Of the three million people tested, one out of three was positive for the virus."

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I was just about to add that **one million in three** would be understood as the OP intended but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't omit the **"million"**.

One out of 3 million: **1**/3000000
One **million** out of 3 million: **1000000**/3000000